# How to use stored procedure with MVC in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have tried several ways but could not come up with any solution. 
I have stored procedure in database(it is called 'mike') and it returns single columned list(called 'code'). There is already connection been made in Visual Studio(C#) using ADO.NET EntityDataModel. The code as follows:

**In Controller Folder**

```
public class TestController : Controller
{

    TestContext db = new TestContext();
    //
    // GET: /Test/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var test = (from p in db.Mike() select new TestResult { sample = p.code}).ToList<TestResult>();

        return View(test);
    }
```

**In Model Folder**

```
public class TestResult
{
    public string sample { get; set; }
}
```

**Error I am recieving is**

Error   1   'string' does not contain a definition for 'code' and no extension method 'code' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**How can i fix it**

Comment: Your code doesn't have `codetype` anywhere.

Comment: I have edit the question

Comment: You shouldn't access your database directly from the MVC layer (well, not if you don't want maintenance headaches later on). Create a data layer for your application and centralize all database access in that layer. Your MVC layer should only call the public functions of your data layer. Inside the data layer, you can hide the complexities of database access, stored procedures or even remote web services (since some of your data may come from external services but you don't want your MVC layer to care about that.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Procedur (Filter the Items in the Procedure with @Code):

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('Mike', 'IF') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.Mike;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Mike(
    @Code varchar(256)
) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN(--Select Whatever Where Code = @Code);
GO
```

The coresponding Code for Procedure returning single Value in EF6:

```
public static string GetMike(string parCode) 
{
    if (parCode == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("parCode", "parCode cannot be a null reference");

    string r = null;
    using (var db = new YourDbContext())
    {
        r = db.Mike(parCode).First();
    }
    return r;
}
```

Code for Procedures returning n Rows (For example: load it in predefined BindingSource):

```
using (var db = new YourDbContext())
{
     YourBindingBindingSource.DataSource = db.Mike(parCode).ToList();
}
```

(for ToList() -> using System.Data.Entity)